# Text Selection w/ SpellingError class

Tags: wpf, vb.net, text, selection, spell-checking

I've got a WPF textbox which I've enabled SpellChecking. I've added a context menu to it so whenever there is a spelling error, the user can select the word and a drop down menu appears like so:

[image]

Now if you take a look at the drop down menu, there is additional menu items like Search Google and Define. These are very important and should always be there. The problem is that let's say I select these words:

```
monky strt
```

Both of these words are incorrectly spelled however I would like to search google for them. When I proceed to do so instead of selecting both words it selects the first incorrect word in the string. Here's what I mean:

[image]

I selected both words: monky strt yet monky gets selected. **Is there a way of selecting both words regardless of whether they are incorrect or not.** BUT if I select the whole sentence it works fine:

[image]

Here's my code for how I handle all this:

```
Dim index As Integer = 0
    Me.ctrl_TextBox.ContextMenu.Items.Clear()
    'Clearing the existing items
    'Getting the spellcheck suggestions.

    Dim spellingError As SpellingError = Me.ctrl_TextBox.GetSpellingError(Me.ctrl_TextBox.CaretIndex)
    If spellingError IsNot Nothing AndAlso spellingError.Suggestions.Count() >= 1 Then
        For Each suggestion As String In spellingError.Suggestions
            Dim menuItem As New MenuItem()
            menuItem.Header = suggestion
            menuItem.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold
            menuItem.Command = EditingCommands.CorrectSpellingError
            menuItem.CommandParameter = suggestion
            menuItem.CommandTarget = Me.ctrl_TextBox
            Me.ctrl_TextBox.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, menuItem)
            index += 1
        Next
        Dim seperator As New Separator()
        Me.ctrl_TextBox.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, seperator)
        index += 1
        'Adding the IgnoreAll menu item
        Dim IgnoreAllMenuItem As New MenuItem()
        IgnoreAllMenuItem.Header = "Ignore All"
        IgnoreAllMenuItem.Command = EditingCommands.IgnoreSpellingError
        IgnoreAllMenuItem.CommandTarget = Me.ctrl_TextBox
        Me.ctrl_TextBox.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, IgnoreAllMenuItem)
        index += 1
    Else
        'No Suggestions found, add a disabled NoSuggestions menuitem.
        Dim menuItem As New MenuItem()
        menuItem.Header = "No Suggestions"
        menuItem.IsEnabled = False
        Me.ctrl_TextBox.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, menuItem)
        index += 1
    End If

    '.Net 4.0 Supports CustomDictionaries, Option for Adding to dictionary.
    Dim selectionStart As Integer = Me.ctrl_TextBox.GetSpellingErrorStart(Me.ctrl_TextBox.CaretIndex)
    If selectionStart >= 0 Then
        Dim seperator1 As New Separator()
        Me.ctrl_TextBox.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, seperator1)
        index += 1
        Dim AddToDictionary As New MenuItem()
        AddToDictionary.Header = "Add to Dictionary"
        'Getting the word to add
        Me.ctrl_TextBox.SelectionStart = selectionStart
        Me.ctrl_TextBox.SelectionLength = Me.ctrl_TextBox.GetSpellingErrorLength(Me.ctrl_TextBox.CaretIndex)
        'Ignoring the added word.
        AddToDictionary.Command = EditingCommands.IgnoreSpellingError
        AddToDictionary.CommandTarget = Me.ctrl_TextBox
        AddHandler AddToDictionary.Click, AddressOf AddToDictionary_Click
        Me.ctrl_TextBox.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, AddToDictionary)
        index += 1
    End If

    'Common Edit MenuItems.
    Dim seperator2 As New Separator()
    Me.ctrl_TextBox.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, seperator2)
    index += 1
    If ctrl_TextBox.SelectionLength > 0 Then
        'Search
        Dim searchMenuItem As New MenuItem()

        Dim EllipsisSearchString As String = ctrl_TextBox.SelectedText
        If EllipsisSearchString.Length > 16 Then
            EllipsisSearchString = Truncate(ctrl_TextBox.SelectedText, 16) + "..."
        Else
            EllipsisSearchString = Truncate(ctrl_TextBox.SelectedText, 16).ToString
        End If

        searchMenuItem.Header = "Search Google for " + "'" + EllipsisSearchString + "'"
        AddHandler searchMenuItem.Click, AddressOf searchMenuItem_Click
        Me.ctrl_TextBox.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, searchMenuItem)
        index += 1

        Dim EllipsisDefineString As String = ctrl_TextBox.SelectedText
        If EllipsisDefineString.Length > 16 Then
            EllipsisDefineString = Truncate(ctrl_TextBox.SelectedText, 16) + "..."
        Else
            EllipsisDefineString = Truncate(ctrl_TextBox.SelectedText, 16).ToString
        End If

        Dim defineMenuItem As New MenuItem()
        defineMenuItem.Header = "Define " + "'" + EllipsisDefineString + "'"
        AddHandler defineMenuItem.Click, AddressOf defineMenuItem_Click
        Me.ctrl_TextBox.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, defineMenuItem)
        index += 1

        Dim seperator22 As New Separator()
        Me.ctrl_TextBox.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, seperator22)
        index += 1
    End If

    'Cut
    Dim cutMenuItem As New MenuItem()
    cutMenuItem.Command = ApplicationCommands.Cut
    Me.ctrl_TextBox.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, cutMenuItem)
    index += 1
    'Copy
    Dim copyMenuItem As New MenuItem()
    copyMenuItem.Command = ApplicationCommands.Copy
    Me.ctrl_TextBox.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, copyMenuItem)
    index += 1
    'Paste
    Dim pasteMenuItem As New MenuItem()
    pasteMenuItem.Command = ApplicationCommands.Paste
    Me.ctrl_TextBox.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, pasteMenuItem)
    index += 1
    Dim seperator3 As New Separator()
    Me.ctrl_TextBox.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, seperator3)
    index += 1
    'Delete
    Dim deleteMenuItem As New MenuItem()
    deleteMenuItem.Command = ApplicationCommands.Delete
    Me.ctrl_TextBox.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, deleteMenuItem)
    index += 1
    Dim seperator4 As New Separator()
    Me.ctrl_TextBox.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, seperator4)
    index += 1
    'Select All
    Dim selectAllMenuItem As New MenuItem()
    selectAllMenuItem.Command = ApplicationCommands.SelectAll
    Me.ctrl_TextBox.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, selectAllMenuItem)
    index += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

So I finally managed to solve this by removing:

```
'.Net 4.0 Supports CustomDictionaries, Option for Adding to dictionary.
Dim selectionStart As Integer = Me.ctrl_TextBox.GetSpellingErrorStart(Me.ctrl_TextBox.CaretIndex)
If selectionStart >= 0 Then
    Dim seperator1 As New Separator()
    Me.ctrl_TextBox.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, seperator1)
    index += 1
    Dim AddToDictionary As New MenuItem()
    AddToDictionary.Header = "Add to Dictionary"
    'Getting the word to add
    Me.ctrl_TextBox.SelectionStart = selectionStart
    Me.ctrl_TextBox.SelectionLength = Me.ctrl_TextBox.GetSpellingErrorLength(Me.ctrl_TextBox.CaretIndex)
    'Ignoring the added word.
    AddToDictionary.Command = EditingCommands.IgnoreSpellingError
    AddToDictionary.CommandTarget = Me.ctrl_TextBox
    AddHandler AddToDictionary.Click, AddressOf AddToDictionary_Click
    Me.ctrl_TextBox.ContextMenu.Items.Insert(index, AddToDictionary)
    index += 1
End If
```